# Firebase auth.currentUser.reload() crashing web page

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I was trying to implement email verification and I discovered that the currentUser object isn't updated automatically after the email has been verified. The firebase docs suggested using the auth.reload() function to refresh the currentUser object, but the moment the function is called, the webpage just hangs and becomes so unresponsive that you can't even close the tab. I dont know what the problem is. Here's the code below

```
verified: async () => {
    try {
        await firebase.auth().currentUser.reload();
        return firebase.auth().currentUser.emailVerified;
    } catch(ex){
        console.log(ex)
    }
}
```

It doesn't even console any exception. The page just becomes entirely unresponsive

Answer (score -1):

Please use JavaScript Promises,
reload method returns a promise.

Read more about promises here https://web.dev/promises/

Comment: I also tried it with promise. The outcome was the same